# CSS Sprites - Cross-Browser Rendering

Tags: css

I've been learning about CSS Sprites. I have been skeptical because cross-browser compatibility is a high priority for my site. Don't CSS sprites cause problems with this considering they rely on positioning? IE6 is specifically a concern for me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is supposed to work in all browsers, including IE6. Although a while back I've experienced problems with it in IE6 in a very specific circumstance which I unfortunately don't recall in detail anymore. The symptom was that the sprite was wrongly positioned, but I at least recall that it was an easy fix. So whenever you run into problems, just ask a question here and we'll help. I can recommend [IETester](http://my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) to test the IE6 behaviour.

For the case you're still interested, I'd recommend you [this article](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites/).

Answer (score 2):

No that's the beauty of CSS Sprites, they work well across all modern browsers, including IE6.  The only time you may have an issue is if you're using transparent PNG's, but there are fixes for that on IE6 as well. I highly recommend using them for small images.  They're especially useful for things like button states, etc. where you have Up, Down, Over, etc.